Adding nodes in compositing
While following Blender Guru's donut tutorial, I became stuck in the compositing part. I couldn't figure out why any nodes I added on the compositing nodetree wouldn't appear on this screen other than the three below.
Here is the .blend file: 


@Joachim , just figured out how to add the .blend file, I updated this post with it.
